# How do I pull random rows from multiple columns and insert them into another table?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to combine rows from three different tables into another table. I have replicated this in my db-fiddle tables and query below. My issue is that if each table has 3 rows in it, then I should have 27 possible combinations but I am only getting 3. I understand why I am only getting three but I don't know how I can change it to do what I want. As it is now, if the random number selected is 3 it pulls the id = 3 from each table. I want the number to be random for each table.

Practice table and query

```
create table First (id int(10), first varchar(255));
Insert into First (id, first) values (1, 'John'), (2, 'Bill'), (3, 'Chad');
create table Middle (id int(10), middle varchar(255));
Insert into Middle (id, middle) values (1, 'Ethan'), (2, 'Dave'), (3, 'Ron');                                                
create table Last (id int(10), last varchar(255));
Insert into Last (id, last) values (1, 'Smith'), (2, 'Miller'), (3, 'Darnold');
create table Full (id int(10) auto_increment primary key, full varchar(255)); 
insert into Full (id) values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10);
```

```
Update Full u1
join (select id,
             @i:=Floor(1+ RAND() * 3),
             (select concat(l.last, ', ', f.first, ' ', m.middle) 
              from First as f, Middle as m, Last as l
              where f.id = @i and m.id = @i and l.id = @i) full 
      from Full) u2
on u1.id = u2.id
set u1.full = u2.full;
select * from Full
```

Edit: I am trying to avoid exact duplicates.

Comment: Start by looking up JOIN and its associated syntax and replace `from First as f, Middle as m, Last as l`

Comment: The columns I am pulling data from are not related. I don't see how using a ```join``` would help

Comment: Well then you will need 3 random numbers instead of only 1 `@i and @j and @k`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need 3 random numbers to improve your mix

```
Update Full u1
join (select id,
             @i:=Floor(1+ RAND() * 3),
             @j:=Floor(1+ RAND() * 3),
             @k:=Floor(1+ RAND() * 3),
             (select concat(l.last, ', ', f.first, ' ', m.middle) 
              from First as f, Middle as m, Last as l
              where f.id = @i and m.id = @j and l.id = @k) full 
      from Full) u2
on u1.id = u2.id
set u1.full = u2.full;
```

And using a proper JOIN mechanism

```
Update Full u1
join (select id,
             @i:=Floor(1+ RAND() * 3),
             @j:=Floor(1+ RAND() * 3),
             @k:=Floor(1+ RAND() * 3),
             (select concat(l.last, ', ', f.first, ' ', m.middle) 
              from First as f
                left join Middle m on m.id = @j
                left join Last l on l.id = @k
              where f.id = @i ) full 
      from Full) u2
on u1.id = u2.id
set u1.full = u2.full;
```

Comment: That is a huge step towards where I need to go. I still need to figure out a way to protect against duplicates, but I'll mark this as the answer. Sometimes the answer is right in front of you lol. Thanks a bunch

Comment: With only 3 possible random numbers 1,2,3 you are bound to get duplicates. If you had a larger sample you would get less collisions

Comment: For sure. My sample is so small to help me easily spot duplicates. My actual tables are much larger, but I still want to prevent duplicates if possible. I might run the query in some sort of loop and replace duplicates. If I figure out a solution I'll update my question